# doctrine2 zf2 form collection not render element

Tags: forms, collections, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, one-to-many

**UPDATE:** I just work until version 2.2.5 of ZF2 if I upgrade to 2.2.6 on, the item is not displayed on the form.

- ZF2 2.3.1
- PHP 5.4.4
- Doctrine2: Master

I have a problem with the bind () the form. When I try to show an element of the Zend\Form\Collection fieldset appears empty.

I have reviewed the tutorial [Doctrine Hydrator](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md) but I can not fix it.

The relationship between the entities is quite simple:

- Product (OneToMany) $images
- Image (ManyToOne) $product

This only happens when I add a new product, if I edit a product with image (action edit), FormCollection element shown on the form.

Product Entity

```
class Product 
{

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=false, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $images;

    public function __construct()    
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();    
    }

    public function addImages(Collection $images)
    {
        foreach ($images as $image)
        {
            $image->setProduct($this);
            $this->images->add($image);
        }
    }

    public function removeImages(Collection $images)
    {
        foreach ($images as $image)
        {
            $image->setProduct(null);
            $this->images->removeElement($image);
        }
    }

    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

}
```

Image Entity

```
class Image
{
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $product;

    public function setProduct(Product $product = null)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

Product Form

```
class ProductForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{

    public function __construct($sl)
    {
        $objectManager = $sl->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

        parent::__construct('product-form');

        $this->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')
             ->setAttribute('method', 'post')
             ->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager));

        // Add the user fieldset, and set it as the base fieldset
        $productFieldset = new ProductFieldset($sl);
        $productFieldset->setName('product');
        $productFieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
        $this->add($productFieldset);

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Go',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
            )
        ));


        $this->setValidationGroup(array(
            'product',
        ));
    }
```

Product Fieldset

```
class ProductFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{

    public function __construct($sl)
    {
        $objectManager = $sl->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

        parent::__construct('product');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager))
             ->setObject(new Product());


        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden'
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name' => 'images',
            'options' => array(
                'count' => 1,
                'target_element' => new ImageFieldset($objectManager)
            )
        ));
   }
}
```

Image Fieldset

```
class ImageFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{

        public function __construct($objectManager)
        {
            parent::__construct('image');


            $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager))
                 ->setObject(new Image());

            $this->add(array(
                        'name' => 'id',
                        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden'
                        )
            );

            $this->add(array(
                        'name' => 'filename',
                        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\File',
                        'options' => array(
                            'label' => 'Photo Upload',
                            'label_attributes' => array(
                                'class' => 'form-label'
                            ),
                            'multiple' => true,
                            'id' => 'filename'
                        )
                    )
            );
        }

        public function getInputFilterSpecification()
            {
                return array(
                   'id' => array(
                        'required' => false
                    ),
                   'filename' => array(
                        'required'    => true,
                    )
                );
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
public function addAction()
{

        $sl = $this->getServiceLocator();

        $form = new ProductForm($sl);

        $product = new Product();

        $form->bind($product);

        if ($request->isPost()):
              ....
        endif;

        return array('form' => $form);

}
```

Comment: Not sure if its a copy paste issue, however your product entity is missing a `protected $images;` property.

Comment: Right, I forgot to paste `protected $images;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are facing this issue:
[BC break in forms between 2.3.0 and 2.3.1](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6152)

> There's been a BC break in Zend\Form between 2.3.0 and 2.3.1, we just upgraded and stumbled into it.
>   We get instances of our Forms through the FormElementManager as we use custom form elements, the site has been working with <= 2.3.0 but after the 2.3.1 upgrade when we get instances of Forms they no longer have any elements attached.

Some general changes when using the FormElementManager:
[Creating custom elements](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#creating-custom-elements)

```
To use custom elements with the FormElementManager needs a bit more work and most likely a change in how you write and use your forms.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial can help - it's pretty up to date:
[Inject DoctrineORM EntityManager in ZF2 Form](http://www.lewanscheck.de/2013/09/21/inject-doctrine-orm-entitymanager-in-zf2-form/)

It uses the formElementManager and the objectManager awareness.

**It is important to add the elements inside the init() method, not the constructor.**

Please also have a look at the comments where *Michael* states:

> I just found out that in the latest version of ZF2 (I have 2.2.5 here) it´s not necessary any more to pass the entityManager via the module config.
>   You only have to implement the “ObjectManagerAwareInterface” in the form class (as well as the required getter + setter) and you will have access via $this->getObjetManager().